# Can i know the site that is web-based android emulator?

Tags: apk

Now I need to share outputs executed by android apk files. But co-workers don't have android emulator on PC/Mac. I heard there are some web-sites that enable emulate apk files on the web. so does anybody recommend these web sites?

Answer (score 0):

Do u need this to test for your android application?
Then, i dont think there is any.

The closest thing available today is : 
Go to http://tmobile.modeaondemand.com/htc/g1/ and click emulator where u can have a look and feel of android.
But this is more of a marketing demo.
For testing your application no alternative to local emulator that comes along with SDK.